# elementary OS flatpak repository

Tags: repositories, software-sources

Does elementary OS have a flatpak repository of the curated apps from its AppCenter? I'd like to be able to use some applications from the elementary OS AppCenter without having to overhaul my operating system.

Answer (score 1):

Not yet.

All curated apps for AppCenter are currently built as .deb packages. There is a plan to work on moving them all to Flatpak. But this work hasn't been completed yet, mostly due to the fact that there was a team due to go and work on this in person, [but it got delayed due to Covid-19.](https://blog.elementary.io/appcenter-for-everyone-remote-sprint/)

So there's no definitive date yet of when this will be available.